# Display simple scraped values from Loki logs using Grafana

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki, logql

I have some log lines in Loki,

```
[10-Oct-2023 08:22:19 UTC] [1270628]: INFO SEND: Sending 235 emails…
[10-Oct-2023 08:23:19 UTC] [1270628]: INFO SEND: Sending 220 emails…
[10-Oct-2023 08:24:19 UTC] [1270628]: INFO SEND: Sending 442 emails…
```

and I’m trying to create a simple line chart. My progress is:

```
{filename="/var/log/php/error_cli.log"} |~ INFO SEND: Sending \d+ |
pattern <_> <_> INFO: GMAIL_SEND: Sending <cnt> <_>
```

and I’m stuck here. I don’t know how do display those fixed `cnt` (did I even obtain this correctly?) values on the chart, without any aggregation. Just a fluctuating line over time, showing at each point values like `235`, `220`, `442`

Some help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You cannot extract value to be directly plotted at graph: since generally there is no guarantee in time between log records with those value, Grafana expects you to aggregate your values. If your logs are incoming with guaranteed one minute interval, and you'll select time range for you dashboard appropriately, you'll see you initial values even after aggregation.

To aggregate over one of the labels in Loki, you need to use [`unwrap`](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/query/query_examples/#unwrap-examples) command, for aggregation function `sum_over_time` to treat said label as value.

```
sum_over_time({filename="/var/log/php/error_cli.log"} |~ INFO SEND: Sending \d+ |
pattern <_> <_> INFO SEND: Sending <cnt> <_> | unwrap cnt [$__interval])
```

More on unwrapping labels [here](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/query/metric_queries/#unwrapped-range-aggregations).

[Here](https://play.grafana.org/explore?panes=%7B%22AlU%22:%7B%22datasource%22:%22ac4000ca-1959-45f5-aa45-2bd0898f7026%22,%22queries%22:%5B%7B%22refId%22:%22A%22,%22expr%22:%22sum_over_time%28%7Bfilename%3D%5C%22%2Fvar%2Flog%2Fnginx%2Faccess.log%5C%22%7D%20%20%7C%20pattern%20%60%3C_%3E%20-%20-%20%5B%3C_%3E%5D%20%5C%22%3C_%3E%20%3C_%3E%20HTTP%2F%3C_%3E%5C%22%20%3C_%3E%20%3Cbody_bytes_sent%3E%20%5C%22%3C_%3E%5C%22%20%5C%22%3C_%3E%5C%22%20%3C_%3E%20%3Ccountry%3E%60%20%7C%20unwrap%20body_bytes_sent%20%5B5m%5D%29%22,%22queryType%22:%22range%22,%22datasource%22:%7B%22type%22:%22loki%22,%22uid%22:%22ac4000ca-1959-45f5-aa45-2bd0898f7026%22%7D,%22editorMode%22:%22code%22%7D%5D,%22range%22:%7B%22from%22:%22now-6h%22,%22to%22:%22now%22%7D%7D%7D&schemaVersion=1&orgId=1) is demo of similar query

Comment: How about a gauge? Could I show the last value found in the last log entry? In my example 442

Comment: @Dude, I think yes. In that case no unwrapping is needed, simply use your own query on Stat panel, and select Calculate values Last. (it's not tested, just a general understanding)